# :first-child not being applied

Tags: css, css-selectors

On [this page](https://www.thevinepress.com.au/), I want to hide the incorrect HTML displayed above the logo. It is generated by an old plugin we are replacing soon.

To start with, I tried the CSS:

```
.vine-home-block-grapes:first-child {display: none;}
```

but this does not remove the highlighted block below:
[image]

Can you help me determine why please?

Comment: That element, `.vine-home-block-grapes`, is not the first child. It's the 4th child.

Comment: You should really post your code in the question instead of an image and a link. Your problem is that the element with `class='vine-home-block-grapes'` is not the first-child under its parent. The `first-child` is the `<p>` tag.

Comment: @MalikAsif: No, it applies to all elements that have class `.vine-home-block-grapes` *and* are the first children of their parents.

Answer (score 0):

Use css [:first-of-type](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_first-of-type.asp) selector

```
.vine-home-block-grapes:first-of-type{   
    display:none;    
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. It will not work if the first child div does not have that class.

Answer (score 0):

Add this script. It would work fine without any problem:

```
<script>
    var fourthChild = document.body.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
    document.body.removeChild(fourthChild);
</script>
```

Thanks to @FelixKling

Comment: Wouldn't this hide *every* 4th child?

Comment: It would hide the fourth child of body-tag only @FelixKling. If i'm wrong please do point out me, my pleasure.

Comment: That would make it difficult to show the element again at some point. It will also suddenly break when the structure changes and another div is inserted before it. Basically, anything that solely relies on position is an inferior solution.

Answer (score 0):

That selector won't work as the element you are attempting to select is not the `:first-child` of its parent.

One way to do what you want is select all elements with that class name, set their styles as you wish and then, using a new rule with the sibling selector, override those styles for any element of that class appearing later in the parent.

```
.vine-home-block-grapes{
    display:none;
}
.vine-home-block-grapes~.vine-home-block-grapes{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the child elements in a `<div>` so the element can BE the first child of its wrapping element. Right now, your element is not the first child of `<body>`  See the experiment here to show how :first-child doesn't work as expected, because really it's not the first child of its parent.

```css
p:first-child {
  background-color: aqua;
}
.vino:first-child {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
WORKS
<p>First</p>
<p>Second</p>
<p>Third</p>

DOESN'T WORK (because none of these are the first child of its parent, in this case, <body>
<p class="vino">First</p>
<p class="vino">Second</p>
<p class="vino">Third</p>

Adding a wrapping div works.
<div>
  <p class="vino">First</p>
  <p class="vino">Second</p>
  <p class="vino">Third</p>
</div>
```